# What is a xul runner? 

Tags: xul, xulrunner

The reason I ask is because every e-mail that I get with a link attached I keep getting " Platform Version 1.9.0.4 not compatible with min version>=1.9.0.5  max version<=1.9.0.5.

I don't have a clue how to get rid of xul runner or what I need to do in order for my computer to accept xul or whatever I need to do. Can someone please provide me with step by step (and I mean very explicit step by step) directions on how to do whatever it is I need to do to get this fixed?

Comment: Every e-mail? Or you mean every attachment of a given type? What's your e-mail client software?

Answer (score 1):

XUL is a tool created by Mozilla Corporation (the folks that made Firefox and Thunderbird) to make writing their applications more like writing applications for the web.

With that said, if you're using Firefox to view webmail when you're having this issue or using Thunderbird and having this issue, I would uninstall any plugins you have installed and check it then. If that still doesn't resolve the problem, try uninstalling and reinstalling the application you're using to view the message in.

Answer (score 0):

While this is the wrong place for this question, you could try asking in mozilla support:
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Ask+a+question